# Allure Report commands don't work in bash

Tags: node.js, allure, wdio

This is bizarre. If I run commands in powershell, it works fine, but if I run any allure commands in bash it throws the following errors:

```
$ allure generate allure-results --clean

C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

Any allure command I run gives me that result. But it is installed and if I simply switch to powershell and run the exact same command in the same repository- it works as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

You should install `allure`, if you are Mac and can use this command:

```
brew install allure.
```

More info could refer: https://docs.qameta.io/allure/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32139544)